# how many Invariant subspace there are.

Tags: linear-algebra

let $ T: \begin{align*} \
\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^4
\end{align*}$ liner transformtion. define $T(a,b,c,d) = (-b,a,-d,c)$

are there a finite or infinite number of Invariant subspaces?

I have found that $\forall v \in V span( v,T(v))$ is  Invariant subspace and the Dimension of Invariant subspace can be 0,2 or 4.

proof for $\forall v\neq 0 \in V span( v,T(v))$ is  Invariant subspace

let $v  \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R^4}$  than $T(\alpha v +\beta T(v))= \alpha T(v) + \beta T(T(v)) = \alpha T(v)  - \beta v  \in span( v,T(v))   $

however, it does not prove that there are infinite invariant subspaces. 
I had thought that any time I can choose for some $v \in \mathbb{R^4}$ such that $v \notin W_i $ and it will be a new Invariant subspace. however, it could be that after finite times of that algorithm  $\forall v' \in \mathbb{R^4}$ $span(v',T(v'))$ will generate a Invariant subspace that already exist.

the Characteristic polynomial of T is $ P_T = (x^2+1)^2$

Comment: 1) What is the question (there is no question mark)? 2) What have you tried? 3) Have you considered eigenspaces (among which there is a kernel if exists.

Comment: thank you 1,2) I edited it 3) I consider it and the eigenspaces of the kernel are all $\mathbb{R^4}$  than it failed

Comment: You only have to express each output in terms of a standard basis to see the invariant spaces.

Comment: but it doesn't imply that there are infinite invariant subspaces. it easy to notice that span{$e_1,e_2$} and span{$e_3,e_4$} are invariant subspaces but there are more.

Comment: First of all, there can't be infinitely many invariant spaces. Secondly, the roots of the characteristic polynomial you got (of your operator defined on a real vector space) are complex numbers.

Comment: How any polynomial, apart from the zero-polynomial, have infinitely many eigenvalues?

Comment: BTW, the minimal polynomial is $x^2+1$.

Comment: there can be infinitely invariant spaces for example for $T:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}T(v)=v$ all subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$ is invariant space

Comment: @amd for an example $span <(1,1,1,1) , (-1,1,-1,1)> $ is  invariant subspaces and look in the question I will add a proof for that

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that. An informal argument: Let $W_v=\operatorname{span}(v,T(v))$, which is a plane in $\mathbb R^4$. Obviously, if $v'\ne W_v$, then $W_{v'}\ne W_v$, and for any finite union of planes there is a vector that’s not a member of that set, so for any finite set of invariant subspaces of $T$ you can always find another.

Comment: @amd is not Obvious because let v =(1,0,0,0), and v' = (2,0,0,0) $v \neq v'$ and $span (v,T(v) = span (v' , T(v)$ and is not obivous tha there is a vector that's not a member because if you will do that 3 times there arn't a vector that not a member of at least one of the subspaces

Comment: Read my comment again more carefully: I said _union_ of planes, not _sum_, nor did I say that we can take $v'\ne v$ to get different planes. There’s an (obvious) typo in that comment, though: instead of $v'\ne W_v$ (which is nonsensical), it should say $v'\notin W_v$.

Comment: @amd but it can be that after finite times of that algorithm $\forall v' \in \mathbb{R^4} span (v',T(v')) $ are subspace that already created by another vector. that was the same idea that I though

Comment: That’s not possible. Think about the analogous situation in $\mathbb R^2$: can any finite number of lines pass through _every_ point on the plane?